External library stops working when the production angular app is built
Hello I am building an app which uses the library leaflet.heat. In order to be used it has to be imported as follows:
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat';

...
// Then it can be used:
  private addHeatmapToMap(heatmapData: L.HeatLatLngTuple[]) {
   ...
    let heatmap = L.heatLayer(heatmapData, { radius: 10, max: 200, gradient: { 0.1: 'yellow', 0.4: 'orange', 0.6: 'red', 0.8: 'white' }, minOpacity: 0.8 });
   ...
  }

This works as expected when using ng serve. But when the app is built to be used in a docker container with ng build --configuration production --output-path=/dist the functions that are derived from L. which depend on the import of leaflet.heat stop working.
My first guess is that angular removes the import during the build process because there is no direct use of that import in the component but I have no idea how can I indicate angular to not do that.
The versions used are:
    angular 18:
    ...
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "leaflet.heat": "^0.2.0",
    ...
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.12",
    "@types/leaflet.heat": "^0.2.4",


Dockerfile:
#################
# Build the app #
#################
FROM node:22-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --fetch-timeout=600000 
COPY . .

RUN ng build --configuration production --output-path=/dist

################
# Run in NGINX #
################
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=build /dist/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# When the container starts, replace the env.js with values from environment variables
CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "envsubst < /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/environment/env.template.js > /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/environment/env.js && exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]


The library probably was tree shaken and removed when you ran angular build with optimizations.
First we need to add this script to assets folder, which is also a configuration on the assets array of angular.json.
Then import the script explicitly through the scripts folder of angular.json.
angular.json:
  ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/app",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
        "assets": [ 
          "src/favicon.ico", 
          "src/assets", 
          "./node_modules/leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"
        ],
        "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
        "scripts": [
          ...
          "src/assets/leaflet-heat.js",
          ...
        ]
      },
      ...


I already tried but it makes not difference: "scripts": [               "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",               "node_modules/leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"             ]" 

@nck You have to first move the script to assets folder, then access it, updated my answer!

@nck You should try different variations of imports in scripts, like /assets/leaflet-heat.js if my answer scripts value does not work

It does not seem to work. It never finds the scripts at build time. I have something similar for the images of leaflet and there is no issue there.

@nck This should work, try npm run build and verify the leaflet script is in the dist folder, then inspect and check if the script is added properly, you should start the angular application, and try checking the correct path to view the script like http://localhost:4200/leaflet-heat.js, updated my answer also

I can see the heatmap library in the dist folder, but still the same exception when the function is called me.heatLayer is not a function

@nck ok then the script should be set with the proper path, this you can try trial and error, you can also check if the script is embedded in the html using chorme inspector

Maybe you are not properly installing the project dependencies upon creating the Dockerfile? But if that's not the problem, I'd use the scripts array in angular.json:
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
  "node_modules/leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"
]

Or you can make sure Angular does not remove that in tree-shaking by importing it as a side effect.
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js';


I added my dockerfile for completion. But I do not think that is the problem because the leaftlet library and other libraries are correctly working. Is just this function that depends on leaflet-heatmap that does not work.
If I change from import 'leaflet-heat'; to  import 'leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js'; it will not compile Namespace '"/app/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'HeatLayer'.

Maybe it's with how typescript checks your imports. Add this to your tsconfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}


Changing the option allowSyntheticDefaultImports to true`` does not seem to make any impact in the error '"/app/node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member 'HeatLayer'. Tahe other option was already in true.

I am not sure if it is the same issue, but I had issues with leaflet.markercluster in production.
While the application was working on my local machine using ng serve, L.markerClusterGroup did not work when deployed on the production server. (I forgot how the exact error looked like.) Anyways, I found following workaround:
import * as leaflet from 'leaflet';

import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.markercluster';

// workaround for angular 18, otherwise leaflet.markercluster doesn't work
declare let L: typeof leaflet;

In addition, I have the plugin's script file added to angular.json.
Maybe that helps fixing your problem?

I just tried but as soon as I do that the static analysis for other types stops working already in developemnt with /node_modules/@types/leaflet/index"' has no exported member named 'HeatLatLngTuple'.
